# Count the duplicate columns of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix such as:

```
A=
   1 0 0 1 1 0 0
   0 0 1 0 0 1 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Now I want to compute the number of duplicate columns. For example, my duplicate column is

```
1
0
0 
1
```

with number of duplicate is 2 . And the other my duplicate column is

```
0 
1 
0 
0
```

with number of duplicate is 3
Besides, I also want to calculate the number of zero column. In my case have 1 columns that has 0 value for all elements (2-th column)
I would like you matlab to resolve my problem. Please help me to do it. This is my matlab code. However, I does not work perfectly

```
numcol=0;
n=100;% the number of columns
for i=1:n
  for j=(i+1):n
    if(nnz(A(:,i)-A(:,j))==0) % A is matrix kxn
        numcol=numcol+1;
    end

 end
     if(nnz(A(:,i))==0)
        countzeros=countzeros+1;
     end
```

end
Update:
My output that I want are

```
1
0  
0 
1
```

with duplicate 2

```
0 
1 
0 
0
```

with duplicate 3
zero column is 1

Comment: You can simply do `isequal(A(:,1),A(:,i))` in your for loop. In this case, the for loop should be `for i=2:n` and if isequal evaluates as true, increment the counter.

Comment: @user8264 please include the desired output you want...

Comment: It is not exactly a duplicate of the suggested question, as in this question it is explicitely asked *how many* occurrences each column has. In the linked question, it is only asked (and answered) how to find rows, which have any duplicates at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unique()`-function for this, as it can find unique rows. Therefore, you have to transpose your matrix A. After that, a simple counting of unique_ids (3rd output variable from `unique()`) does give you the desired result.

```
A=[1 0 0 1 1 0 0
   0 0 1 0 0 1 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1 0 0 0 1 0 0];

A = transpose(A); % // transpose to be able to find unique rows (not cols)
[A_unique,~,u_id] = unique(A, 'rows'); % // find unique rows and their unique id

occurrences = histc(u_id, unique(u_id)); % // count occurrences of unique ids

% // visualize result: unique columns, last row: number of occurrences
[transpose(A_unique); transpose(occurrences)]
```

It does print:

```
    ans =

     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     3     1     2
```

Which has to be read column-wise as, where first 4 rows describe the original column and the last row describes the amount of occurrences:

```
% // column [0;0;0;0]: 1 occurrence
% // column [0;1;0;0]: 3 occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easily solved using a map data type - which incidentally is also a very good data structure for holding the result. Sadly, Matlab is not very good at data structures in my opinion. One solution is using the java hidden behind Matlab. You can however also use built in Matlab functions. One quick to write, but quite crude, solution is:

```
A = [1,0,0,1,1,0,0;0,0,1,0,0,1,1;0,0,0,0,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,1,0,0];

map = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','double');
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    key = mat2str(A(:,i));
    if map.isKey(key)
        map(key) = map(key)+1;
    else
        map(key) = 1;
    end
end
```

This will represent the columns as a char-type and use that to count how many of each column you have.
The resulting variable `map` will contain all the information:
`map.keys` will give you a list of the string representation of all the different columns in `A`, and if you are interested in how many there are of a specific column you get that number by: `map('[0;1;0;0]')` (this example will return the value `3`, since there are 3 columns of that type). And you can easily loop over the keys in the map if you for example want to remove the columns from the map that only occur once you can do something like:

```
keys = map.keys;
for i = 1:numel(keys)
    if map(keys{i}) == 1
        map.remove(keys{i})
    end
end
```

Notice however this will not work for all kinds of matrices! Matrices with integer values with less that 15 digits will do fine. However if two different values of the matrix are represented by the same string (eg. `1000000000000000` and `1000000000000001` are both represented as `'1e+15'`) then you may very well get in trouble, which is a bit more complicated to solve.